# Task ContinueWith OnlyOnFaulted still gets CurrentDomain.UnhandledException

Tags: vb.net, exception, task-parallel-library, async-await

I am trying to get a solid grasp on async/await and TPL so I am trying some things out. I see that there are a lot of similar questions, but I am still unable to figure out what is going on here. Apologies if I am missing something obvious or already answered.

If you dislike vb.net please [convert it](http://converter.telerik.com/) ;)

Why does CurrentDomain.UnhandledException still occur? I thought it would be observed when I access task.Exception and return true in handle and since it is observed it would not automatically propagate?

```
      Public Function ContinueWith_ExceptionHandling_Flattening() As Threading.Tasks.Task(Of Integer)
        Dim s As String = "ContinueWith_ExceptionHandling_Flattening"
        Dim context = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()

        AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf CurrentDomain_UnhandledException

        Dim t As Task(Of Integer) = Task.Run(Function() ThrowException(0, ""))
        t.ContinueWith(Function(a) CreateAndShowResultForm(a.Result, s), Threading.CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted, context) 'doesnt run if t faulted!
        t.ContinueWith(AddressOf HandleTask_Exception, Threading.CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted, context) 'only runs if t faulted

        Return t
    End Function


    Private Sub HandleTask_Exception(x As task)
        x.Exception.Flatten.Handle(Function(ex)
                                       Select Case ex.GetType
                                           Case GetType(NoNullAllowedException)
                                               MessageBox.Show("NoNullAllowedException ...handled by HandleTask_Exception")
                                           Case Else
                                               MessageBox.Show(ex.Message & " ...handled by HandleTask_Exception")
                                       End Select
                                       Return True
                                   End Function)
    End Sub

'THIS IS STILL BEING HIT (I am looking for explanation as to why)
   Private Sub CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(sender As Object, e As UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
        MessageBox.Show("CurrentDomain_UnhandledException:  " & CType(e.ExceptionObject, Exception).Message)
    End Sub



'Calling code
 Public Async Function ContinueWith_ExceptionHandling_Flattening_Helper() As Task(Of Integer)
            Return Await cls.ContinueWith_ExceptionHandling_Flattening
    End Function
```

Comment: It is funny that your source code is in VB.Net and yet you tagged C# without even tagging Vb.Net o_O

Comment: last time I tagged vb.net. and C# and admin remove my vb.net tag and left the c#.

Comment: You should note that unobserved task exceptions do not cause `UnhandledException` to be raised. This event is raised in `async void` methods and unhandled exceptions in threads.

Comment: I may have left out important info. This is called from an async event handler

Comment: The unhandled exception (caught if I wrap the call to the "helper" function) is my original exception. I could not get unobserved task to happen (for experimentation) without taking away the handling and forcing garbage collection

Answer (score 2):

In modern code, you should use `await` instead of `ContinueWith`. It's much easier than messing around with task schedulers, aggregate exceptions, and whatnot:

```
public async Task<int> ContinueWith_ExceptionHandling_FlatteningAsync()
{
  string s = "ContinueWith_ExceptionHandling_Flattening";

  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;

  Task<int> t = Task.Run(() => ThrowException(0, ""));
  try
  {
    var result = await t;
    CreateAndShowResultForm(result, s);
    return result;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    HandleTask_Exception(ex);
    throw;
  }
}

private void HandleTask_Exception(Exception ex)
{
  MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + " ...handled by HandleTask_Exception");
}
```

Comment: Though this doesn't answer my question I appreciate the advice

Comment: Stephen, That switch statement isn't valid in c#, maybe it could be valid in VB.net(I don't know) but not c#.